# How can I implement this type of redirect after post method in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, get

I am currently creating an MVC application that is currently getting a value from a post from a webhook.  I think that the problem is that the application is getting the value from the POST verb but then it is not displaying it because the Get verb is being used to display the View so both Verbs are counter acting each other.

The webhook will fire A Json payload to my application successfully because I have code in it that will send the Json payload in a variable via email to my email account.

```
Dim body = issue.issue.key
mail.Body = body
```

That is in a try catch block because in order for it to have a value it must have a value in it and the application will perform the GET first, so there is a null value in **the body variable**, then it does the POST to get the value but it will not display the value, refreshing will just perform the GET preventing it from being displayed.  How can I perform both actions at the same time so I can display a value in a ViewBag for example.

```
ViewBag.response = status + key
```

This is the type of structure that I would like to implement to try and fix the error but I do not know how to complete all of the steps:

[image]

This is what I have got so far:

The POST is coming in from a webhook and I am reading it like this.

```
Dim reader As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.InputStream)
Dim rawSendGridJSON As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
Dim tempVar As Rootobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Rootobject)(rawSendGridJSON)
System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError(rawSendGridJSON)
```

I am then trying to store the post values in a table like this:

```
Public Function CallBack(tempTable as temporaryTable)
    Dim tempVar As Rootobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Rootobject)(rawSendGridJSON)
tempVar = temporaryTable.tempVar
```

I then save the new items in the actual table in the database, then I try to display it in a view on another page.  This is not working correctly and the problem lies with this line, as the post is not being correctly read in at the right time.  (The value is processing correctly as I can use an email method to send the variables in an email back to the application but this application needs to be real-time efficient code).

Is there a better way to use this method and how can I invoke this process that I want to do properly so that I can display the correct information?

**Update**

To clarify, there are two posts that are happening, the first one is when the user enters in information and submits it.  This is then stored in a database and send to JIRA via email.  Once JIRA receives the information, it is sends a HTTP POST webhook JSON Payload back to my application with updated information. I then have deserialized the JSON Payload into a variable called **issueKey**.

The problem is that on the View page that the information is sent to will automatically display a null value first before the value is sent to it, I want the application to work so that it will actually display/store in a database the values from the Webhook JSON Payload but I cannot figure out how to display the values.

I have now set up a communication channel from SignalR to my MVC application, at the moment it is being received by the MVC and I have set up a SignalR chat Hub in my MVC application, but I don't know how to integrate them, how can this be done?

Comment: At a quick glance this appears to just be a small workflow containing 2 [Post-Redirect-Gets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). Have you tried implementing it yet?

Comment: @br4d Yes that is exactly what I would like to do but I am unsure how to do it in mvc, for example I have successfully submitted into the database a list of variables (this is linked with JIRA via email so when it is submitted it will enter in the JIRA system), then that will initiate a webhook which will fire a post back to it , I do not know how to display / store this in a database, and then post the new information again and also store the additional information in the table, do you know how I could show me how I could do that part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, there are two flows at work here. The user posts data, which triggers an email to Jira. Then sometime later (usually quite fast, but not always) JIRA triggers a webhook in the web application with some updated information, and you want to display this updated information to the user somehow, or at least inform the user when the updated information comes back from JIRA.

I would implement a standard Post-Redirect-Get for the user initiated part (as per br4d's comment). I.e. a post to store the data in the database and send email to jira, which returns a redirect to a get which shows the data stored in the database.

Now for the other part I would use [signalr](http://www.asp.net/signalr) to set up some sort of communications channel to the user. The webook could then send a signal (of sorts) through the communication channel to the users browser and either display the data, or trigger a refresh of the page (if you are updating the database with data from Jira).

It is unclear if you are doing straigt mvc, or some sort of SPA application, but it is not really important. The users browser has no way of knowing about the webhook (which is a part of the webapplication and unrelated to the users session), and you need some sort of communication between the webapplication and the browser, and for this signalr is very very good.